# Update a record if ID exist else Insert values

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp

I am trying to update a value if record exists else insert the values to database. However, that is not working. I have written the below code.

```
 String sqlCheck = "Select * from [UAP].[dbo].[UAP_EMPLOYEE] where EMP_EMPLOYEE_ID = '"+empId+"' ";
    PreparedStatement prpStatementCheck = conn.prepareStatement(sqlCheck);
    prpStatementCheck.setString(1, EMP_EMPLOYEE_ID);
    ResultSet rsCheck=prpStatementCheck.executeQuery();
    String check=null;

     while((rsCheck.next())
    {
         if(rsCheck.next()>0)
          update statement; 
         else
             Insert Statement; 
    }
```

Comment: What error do you get when debugging ? And at which line does it occure?

Comment: Can you try without [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As EMP_EMPLOYEE_ID field is an INTEGER type, use `setInt` rather than `setString`:

```
String sqlCheck = "Select * from [UAP].[dbo].[UAP_EMPLOYEE] where EMP_EMPLOYEE_ID = ?";
PreparedStatement prpStatementCheck = conn.prepareStatement(sqlCheck);
prpStatementCheck.setInt(1, EMP_EMPLOYEE_ID);
```

Comment: Reimeus, EMP_EMPLOYEE_ID is Integer in DB.

Answer (score 1):

setString should be used with bound variables:
Your sql string should look like this:

```
"Select * from [UAP].[dbo].[UAP_EMPLOYEE] where EMP_EMPLOYEE_ID = ?"
```

What is the version of your SqlServer?
If it is 2008 or higher, you can leverage the [UPSERT](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3739131/UPSERT-Functionality-in-SQL-Server-2008.htm) command.

Answer (score 1):

That condition while((rsCheck.next()) will only be executed if the employee exists.
Otherwise,  that code

```
if(rsCheck.next()>0)
      update statement; 
     else
         Insert Statement;
```

is unreachable.
You could use something like that:

```
boolean exists = false;

 while((rsCheck.next())
{
     update statement; 
     exists = true;
}
if(!exists) insert statement;
```

Comment: if id is the key, you can just if(rs.next()) update else insert