# Update if ID available in Database otherwise insert

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jsp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Update a record if ID exist else Insert values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924979/update-a-record-if-id-exist-else-insert-values)

I am trying to update a value if the record exists else insert the values in the database. However, that is not working. I have written the code below :

NOTE: (Moderators, this is a repeated questions that I asked few mins ago. I am not able to edit previous one. Apologies if any inconvenience. Requesting you to delete.)

```
 <%
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://10.222.10.19:1433", "sa", "admin1");



String empId = request.getParameter("empid");
String fName = request.getParameter("fName");
String lName = request.getParameter("lName");


String sqlCheck = "Select * from [UAP].[dbo].[UAP_EMPLOYEE] where EMP_EMPLOYEE_ID = "empId" ";
PreparedStatement prpStatementCheck = conn.prepareStatement(sqlCheck);
prpStatementCheck.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(empId));
prpStatementCheck.setString(2, fName);
prpStatementCheck.setString(3, lName);
ResultSet rsCheck=prpStatementCheck.executeQuery();
String check=null;
boolean exists = false;

 while(rsCheck.next())
{

         Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
         String sql= "UPDATE [UAP].[dbo].[UAP_EMPLOYEE] SET EMP_EMPLOYEE_ID="+empId+", EMP_FNAME='"+fName+"', EMP_LNAME='"+lName+"' WHERE EMP_EMPLOYEE_ID= ?";
         stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
         exists = true;

     }
 if(!exists) 
     {
         String sql2 = "INSERT INTO [UAP].[dbo].[UAP_EMPLOYEE] (EMP_EMPLOYEE_ID, EMP_FNAME, EMP_LNAME ) VALUES (?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement prpStatement1 = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
            prpStatement1.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(empId));

            prpStatement1.setString(2, fName);
            prpStatement1.setString(3, lName);

            prpStatement1.execute();
            prpStatement1.close();   

     }
```

%>

Answer (score 1):

As EMP_EMPLOYEE_ID is an INTEGER field you will need to use:

```
prpStatementCheck.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(empId));
```

Also, you can remove the quotes around this field for the UPDATE string:

```
String sql= "UPDATE  [UAP_EMPLOYEE] SET EMP_EMPLOYEE_ID=" + empId + ", EMP_FNAME='" + fName+"', EMP_LNAME='" + lName + "' WHERE EMP_EMPLOYEE_ID= " + empId;
```

Again for `prpStatement1`:

```
prpStatement1.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(empId));
```

Comment: An exception occurred processing JSP page /dynatree/dbconnection.jsp at line 26

23:   
24:  String sqlCheck = "Select * from [UAP].[dbo].[UAP_EMPLOYEE] where EMP_EMPLOYEE_ID = '"+empId+"' ";
25:  PreparedStatement prpStatementCheck = conn.prepareStatement(sqlCheck);
26:  prpStatementCheck.setString(1, empId);
27:  prpStatementCheck.setString(2, fName);
28:  prpStatementCheck.setString(3, lName);
29:  ResultSet rsCheck=prpStatementCheck.executeQuery();
the index 1 is out of range.

Comment: This error shows that the old syntax is still being used i.e. quotes around EMP_EMPLOYEE_ID, no PreparedStmt placeolders, '?', etc.

Comment: Same error even after changing prpStatement as you suggested.   <br>   An exception occurred processing JSP page /dynatree/dbconnection.jsp at line 26

23:   
24:  String sqlCheck = "Select * from [UAP].[dbo].[UAP_EMPLOYEE] where EMP_EMPLOYEE_ID = "+empId+" ";
25:  PreparedStatement prpStatementCheck = conn.prepareStatement(sqlCheck);
26:  prpStatementCheck.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(empId));
27:  prpStatementCheck.setString(2, fName);
28:  prpStatementCheck.setString(3, lName);
29:  ResultSet rsCheck=prpStatementCheck.executeQuery();

Comment: I updated the changed code that you recommended